# After switching from @Autowired to @Inject the EntityManager is null in the repository

Tags: java, spring, jpa, cdi

I need to switch form Spring annotations to CDI annotations in a service module. Everything works fine but the entity manager is null. If i'm annotating the repository **with @Autowire everything is fine** (the entity manager is injected). When I'm switching to @Inject the entity manager is null and I have no idea why?

Here is the spring context config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- Scan service classes for beans -->
    <context:component-scan
            base-package="com.monitoring.facade, com.monitoring.indication, com.monitoring.app"
            annotation-config="false">
    </context:component-scan>
</beans>
```

The Service Class:

```
@Named
public class IndicatorTreeService implements Serializable{
    //@Autowire - everything ok
    @Inject
    private IndicatorRepository indicatorRepository;

    @Inject
    private IndicatorTreeBuilder indicatorTreeBuilder;

    public List<AbstractIndicatorTreeItem> getIndicatorTreeItems(){
        List<IndicatorVO> indicators = indicatorRepository.getIndicatorQuery().getResultList();
        return indicatorTreeBuilder.buildTree(indicators);
    }
}
```

And the repository:

```
@Named
public class IndicatorRepository{
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    public IndicatorQuery getIndicatorQuery(){
        return new IndicatorQuery(em);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you define META-INF/beans.xml?

Comment: Spring 3.0 and beyond provides support for JSR 330 annotations. What version of spring are you using?

Comment: you configured `annotation-config="false"` which disables annotation processing. Remove this or set to `true` which is the default.

Comment: I have defined a beans.xml (it contains only an empty <beans> tag) and I'm using Spring 3.0.1

Comment: @M.Deinum I have tried also with `annotation-config="true"` and it is the same (still no entity manager)

Comment: Why do you need `@Inject` anyway over `@Autowired`?

Comment: @M.Deinum `@Autowired` is not CDI and we have to get rid of the Spring specific annotations. Maybe the module will be plugged in an app which will not use Spring at all.

Comment: I guess you now have competing conflicts between CDI and Spring. Make sure that CDI isn't wracking havoc here (or spring depends on how you look at it). Make sure you don't have a  beans.xml (as that will trigger CDI injection) and that spring is your only means of control. Basically `annotation-config="false"` disables processing altogether so I believe you aren't using spring (although you think you do).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42642/discussion-between-marius-and-m-deinum)

Comment: Spring is not a CDI implementation.  Spring is a JSR-330 implementation, which only defines basic annotations like `@Inject`

Comment: @M.Deinum you are right there was a conflict between CDI and Spring. I shouldn't have used beans.xml in the service module because I had both Spring and CDI beans. After I removed the beans.xml from the service module and used spring in the web module everything worked fine.